# Relation between main module and related module

Tags: vtiger

I am using **vtiger** and i have created a module and add a document module as related module. I have added some functionality in document as: at least 3 document you have to select. But i want, when he added 3 documents and if he want to add more document then only one field will show when he click on add button.

Its mean I want to know in which table related module are managed?

Answer (score 1):

Related module list is managed in vtiger_relatedlists table. And add function get_attachments from CRMEntity.php for related module to your module.php file to which you have to set relation. (this is just for your information if you don't know). Any question please let me know.